# Find available intervals

Tags: sql

I've got 2 tables, called `Entry` and `Booking`. The idea is: I create an `entry` which has a `start` and an `end` time and then I can create bookings for this `entry`. A `booking` is associated with an `entry` and it also has a `start` and an `end`. A `booking` lies within the time of its `entry`, meaning `booking.start >= entry.start` and `booking.end <= entry.end`. Also, there are no overlapping `bookings` in one `entry`

**"Entry" Table:**

```
id |       start         |           end
----------------------------------------------
1  | 2014-07-24 09:00:00 | 2014-07-24 11:20:00
```

**"Booking" Table:**

```
id |       start         |           end       | entry_id
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2014-07-24 09:10:00 | 2014-07-24 09:40:00 |     1
2  | 2014-07-24 09:50:00 | 2014-07-24 10:20:00 |     1
3  | 2014-07-24 10:50:00 | 2014-07-24 11:20:00 |     1
```

This Example then roughly looks like the following:

```
<-------------- entry 1 interval ---------------------------------->
     <-booking 1->   <-booking 2->                     <-booking 3->
```

Now I'd like to get all the intervals in which entry 1 has no booking yet:

**Desired result:**

```
entry_id |        start        |           end
----------------------------------------------------
1        | 2014-07-24 09:00:00 | 2014-07-24 09:10:00
1        | 2014-07-24 09:40:00 | 2014-07-24 09:50:00
1        | 2014-07-24 10:20:00 | 2014-07-24 10:50:00
```

How do i do this with SQL? (I'm looking for a general solution, though im going to use it in MySQL)

Comment: would be pretty easy (and efficient) using Postgres' range datatype and the overlaps or includes operators that come with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got a bit ugly:

```
SELECT
  e.id                           AS entry_id,
  e.start                        AS start,
  COALESCE(MIN(b1.start), e.end) AS end
FROM entry e
  LEFT JOIN booking b1 ON b1.entry_id = e.id AND b1.start >= e.start AND b1.end <= e.end
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING start < end
UNION
SELECT
  e.id                           AS entry_id,
  b1.end                         AS start,
  COALESCE(MIN(b2.start), e.end) AS end
FROM entry e
  JOIN booking b1 ON b1.entry_id = e.id AND b1.start >= e.start AND b1.end <= e.end
  LEFT JOIN booking b2 ON b2.entry_id = e.id AND b2.start >= b1.end AND b2.end <= e.end
GROUP BY b1.id
HAVING start < end;
```

tested against MySQL; for other SQL-Servers you probably need to include further columns into the `GROUP BY` terms. No MySQL-specific functions used.

What it does?

The statement upto `UNION` determines how much time is left before the first booking and returns up to one row per entry.

The statement after `UNION` selects all bookings for the entry and pairs them with all bookings to the same entry after the booking.

`HAVING` is needed to remove 0-length intervals and should only ruin runtime if many bookings are directly adjacent.

### Bonus:

I this is a slightly modified query suitable for easy selection of entries, bookings which are not fully included inside the entry and ordering:

```
SELECT
  entry_id,
  start,
  end
FROM (
       SELECT
         e.id                           AS entry_id,
         e.start                        AS start,
         COALESCE(MIN(b1.start), e.end) AS end
       FROM entry e
         LEFT JOIN booking b1 ON b1.entry_id = e.id AND b1.start <= e.end AND b1.end >= e.start
       GROUP BY e.id
       UNION
       SELECT
         e.id                           AS entry_id,
         b1.end                         AS start,
         COALESCE(MIN(b2.start), e.end) AS end
       FROM entry e
         JOIN booking b1 ON b1.entry_id = e.id AND b1.start <= e.end AND b1.end >= e.start
         LEFT JOIN booking b2 ON b2.entry_id = e.id AND b2.start >= b1.end AND b2.start <= e.end AND b2.end >= e.start
       GROUP BY b1.id) iq
WHERE start < end AND entry_id = 1
ORDER BY start;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! You've solved it in such a way that i can actually follow what you did and understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

**MS SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ENTRY_ID, 
    b1.BOOK_END_DATE AS INTERVALL_START_DATE, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 b2.BOOK_START_DATE FROM Booking b2 WHERE b1.BOOK_ENTRY_ID = b2.BOOK_ENTRY_ID AND b2.BOOK_START_DATE > b1.BOOK_END_DATE ORDER BY b2.BOOK_START_DATE) AS INTERVALL_END_DATE
    FROM Entry
    JOIN Booking b1 ON ENTRY_ID = b1.BOOK_ENTRY_ID
) AS sub01
WHERE sub01.INTERVALL_START_DATE is not null AND sub01.INTERVALL_END_DATE is not null AND sub01.INTERVALL_START_DATE <> sub01.INTERVALL_END_DATE
UNION 
(SELECT ENTRY_ID, ENTRY_START_DATE, (SELECT TOP 1 BOOK_START_DATE FROM Booking WHERE BOOK_ENTRY_ID = ENTRY_ID AND BOOK_START_DATE > ENTRY_START_DATE ORDER BY BOOK_START_DATE) FROM Entry)
UNION 
(SELECT ENTRY_ID, (SELECT TOP 1 BOOK_END_DATE FROM Booking WHERE BOOK_ENTRY_ID = ENTRY_ID AND BOOK_END_DATE < ENTRY_END_DATE ORDER BY BOOK_END_DATE DESC), ENTRY_END_DATE FROM Entry)
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ENTRY_ID, 
    b1.BOOK_END_DATE AS INTERVALL_START_DATE, 
    (SELECT b2.BOOK_START_DATE FROM Booking b2 WHERE b1.BOOK_ENTRY_ID = b2.BOOK_ENTRY_ID AND b2.BOOK_START_DATE > b1.BOOK_END_DATE ORDER BY b2.BOOK_START_DATE LIMIT 1) AS INTERVALL_END_DATE
    FROM Entry
    JOIN Booking b1 ON ENTRY_ID = b1.BOOK_ENTRY_ID
) AS sub01
WHERE sub01.INTERVALL_START_DATE is not null AND sub01.INTERVALL_END_DATE is not null
UNION
(SELECT e2.ENTRY_ID, e2.ENTRY_START_DATE, (SELECT b2.BOOK_START_DATE FROM Booking b2 WHERE b2.BOOK_ENTRY_ID = e2.ENTRY_ID AND b2.BOOK_START_DATE >= e2.ENTRY_START_DATE ORDER BY b2.BOOK_START_DATE LIMIT 1) FROM Entry e2)
UNION
(SELECT e3.ENTRY_ID, (SELECT b3.BOOK_END_DATE FROM Booking b3 WHERE b3.BOOK_ENTRY_ID = e3.ENTRY_ID AND BOOK_END_DATE <= e3.ENTRY_END_DATE ORDER BY b3.BOOK_END_DATE DESC LIMIT 1), e3.ENTRY_END_DATE FROM Entry e3)
 ) sub02
WHERE sub02.INTERVALL_START_DATE <> sub02.INTERVALL_END_DATE
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0986b/8)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. Instead of having a series of "to"/"from" or "start"/"end" dates which have to stay synchronized with no overlaps, use a design with just one date.

```
CREATE TABLE Entry (
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  EffDate datetime not null,
  State smallint NOT NULL,
  Comment varchar( 100 ),
  primary key( ID, EffDate, State )
);
```

The key here is that there is a record for every state change. States are, essentially, booked (not available) and not booked (available). So when you create an entry, you write a row for when the entry starts and one for when it is over.

```
INSERT INTO Entry( ID, EffDate, State, Comment )
select 1, STR_TO_DATE( '2014-07-24 09:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i' ), -2, 'Entry Open' union all
select 1, STR_TO_DATE( '2014-07-24 11:20', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i' ), 0, 'Entry Closed';
```

These states are zero or negative values. They could be any value, I just chose these because they allow for convenient grouping. There is a state -1 which you'll see in a moment.

There are two queries to give you what you want to know: one query to show you when the entry has been booked and for how long and one query to show when the entry is available and for how long.

```
-- When is the entry available?
  select e1.ID as Entry, e1.Comment as Availability, null as `Booking #`,
         e1.EffDate as `From`, e2.EffDate as `To`
    from Entry e1
    left join Entry e2
      on e2.ID = e1.ID
     and e2.EffDate =(
           select Min( EffDate )
             from Entry
            where ID = e1.ID
              and State >= 0
              and EffDate > e1.EffDate)
   where e1.State <= 0;
```

At this point, the result set looks like this:

```
ENTRY AVAILABILITY  BOOKING # FROM                  TO
1     Entry Open    (null)    July, 24 2014 09:00   July, 24 2014 11:20
1     Entry Closed  (null)    July, 24 2014 11:20   (null)
```

You'll see what the "Booking #" column is for in a moment. The query to show the bookings:

```
-- When is the entry booked?
  select e1.ID as Entry, e1.Comment as Availability, e1.State as `Booking #`,
         e1.EffDate as `From`, e2.EffDate as `To`
    from Entry e1
    join Entry e2
      on e2.ID = e1.ID
     and e2.EffDate =(
           select Min( EffDate )
             from Entry
            where ID = e1.ID
              and State in( -1, 0 )
              and EffDate > e1.EffDate)
   where e1.State > 0;
```

At this point, this results in nothing. There are no bookings yet. So let's generate a booking. As you saw, the entire entry is available so what we're going to do is a set of "booking starts" and "booking ends" state rows with the appropriate times.

```
INSERT INTO Entry( ID, EffDate, State, Comment )
select 1, STR_TO_DATE( '2014-07-24 09:10', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i' ), 1, 'Booked' union all
select 1, STR_TO_DATE( '2014-07-24 09:40', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i' ), -1, 'Booking Available';
```

The state value for a booking is the booking number (1, 2, etc.) and the end of the booking is the final negative state, -1. Now let's see what our queries show, but let's union them together to get a complete look:

```
select *
from(
  (first query)
union
  (second query)
) B
order by B.Entry, B.`From`;

ENTRY AVAILABILITY      BOOKING #   FROM                    TO
1     Entry Open        (null)      July, 24 2014 09:00     July, 24 2014 09:10
1     Booked            1           July, 24 2014 09:10     July, 24 2014 09:40
1     Booking Available (null)      July, 24 2014 09:40     July, 24 2014 11:20
1     Entry Closed      (null)      July, 24 2014 11:20     (null)
```

Another booking comes along. We can see there are time slots available from 9:00 to 9:10 and from 9:40 to 11:20. The bookers decide on 9:50 to 10:20 so we book it by writing a pair of state change records.

```
INSERT INTO Entry( ID, EffDate, State, Comment )
select 1, STR_TO_DATE( '2014-07-24 09:50', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i' ), 2, 'Booked' union all
select 1, STR_TO_DATE( '2014-07-24 10:20', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i' ), -1, 'Booking Available';
```

If they had wanted to start right when the other booking was finished, 10:40, then we could just update the existing "Booking Available" to the end of the second booking, 10:20, and insert the booking 2 record. Once a booking starts, it ends when either the entry becomes available or when another booking starts. It doesn't matter which.

```
ENTRY AVAILABILITY      BOOKING #   FROM                    TO
1     Entry Open        (null)      July, 24 2014 09:00     July, 24 2014 09:10
1     Booked            1           July, 24 2014 09:10     July, 24 2014 09:40
1     Booking Available (null)      July, 24 2014 09:40     July, 24 2014 09:50
1     Booked            2           July, 24 2014 09:50     July, 24 2014 10:20
1     Booking Available (null)      July, 24 2014 10:20     July, 24 2014 11:20
1     Entry Closed      (null)      July, 24 2014 11:20     (null)
```

Finally, the entry is booked from 10:50 to the end of the entry. We write the Booked record but since it goes to the end of the entry anyway, we don't need to end it with a Booking Available row.

```
INSERT INTO Entry( ID, EffDate, State, Comment )
select 1, STR_TO_DATE( '2014-07-24 10:50', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i' ), 3, 'Booked';
```

So now we can see the complete picture:

```
ENTRY AVAILABILITY      BOOKING #   FROM                    TO
1     Entry Open        (null)      July, 24 2014 09:00     July, 24 2014 09:10
1     Booked            1           July, 24 2014 09:10     July, 24 2014 09:40
1     Booking Available (null)      July, 24 2014 09:40     July, 24 2014 09:50
1     Booked            2           July, 24 2014 09:50     July, 24 2014 10:20
1     Booking Available (null)      July, 24 2014 10:20     July, 24 2014 10:50
1     Booked            3           July, 24 2014 10:50     July, 24 2014 11:20
1     Entry Closed      (null)      July, 24 2014 11:20     (null)
```

If someone else want to book, you can look down this list, find where Booking # is null and read across to see the available time remaining: 9:00-9:10, 9:40-9:50, 10:20-10:50. Or you read down the From and Availability columns to see the sequence of actions: the entry came "online" at 9:00, was booked at 9:10, became available at 9:40, booked again at 9:50, available at 10:20, booked at 10:50 until the entry went "offline" at 11:20.

This nice feature of this method is that you don't have to worry about overlapping intervals. Once a state begins, it stays in effect until the next state change. This makes overlaps absolutely impossible.

See the whole thing in action at <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/076e7/1/0)</kbd>